# setrlimit isn't reliable?

Tags: c, time, setrlimit

I'm trying to use [`setrlimit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) to cap the amount of time a process takes. However it doesn't seem to work when I do certain operations like `printf()`.

Here is a test program illustrating the problem:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    struct rlimit limit;
    limit.rlim_cur = 3;
    limit.rlim_max = 3; // send SIGKILL after 3 seconds 
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, &limit);

    // doesn't get killed
    for(i=0; i<1000000; i++)
        printf("%d",i);

    return 0;
}
```

However if I replace the for loop with a different routine like naive fibonacci:

```
int fib(int n) {
    if(n<=1) return 1;
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
int main(void) {
    ...
    fib(100);
    ...
}
```

It works perfectly. What's going on here? Is `setrlimit()` simply unreliable?

Comment: That code doesn't even compile! Let me fix that for you.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Ah thanks! I did some on the fly editing :[

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CPU limit is a limit on *CPU* seconds rather than elapsed time. CPU seconds is basically how many seconds the CPU has been in use and does not necessarily directly relate to the elapsed time.

When you do the `fib` call, you hammer the CPU so that elapsed and CPU time are close (most of the process time is spent using the CPU). That's not the case when printing since most time there is spent in I/O.

So what's happening in your particular case is that the `rlimit` *is* set but you're just not using your three seconds of CPU time before the process finishes.

Changing the `main` as follows causes the signal to be delivered on my system:

```
int main(void) {
    int i;
    struct rlimit limit;
    limit.rlim_cur = 3;
    limit.rlim_max = 3; // send SIGKILL after 3 seconds
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, &limit);

    while (1) {                      // Run "forever".
        for(i=0; i<100000; i++) {
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
        fib(30);                     // some CPU-intensive work.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When you `time` that under Linux, you see:

```
: (much looping).
52670
52671
52672
52673
52674
Killed

real   0m18.719s
user   0m0.944s
sys    0m2.416s
```

In that case, it took almost 20 seconds of elapsed time but the CPU was in use for only 3.36 seconds (user + sys).

Comment: The rest of the time was probably spent blocked waiting for your ultra-slow GNOME/libvte/whatever-based terminal to finish redrawing and read from the pty master device again... :-)

Comment: So how do you limit elapsed time?

Comment: @Dustin, you start up the process with _another_ process which then monitors wall time and, if it's exceeded, kills off the one you're trying to limit.

Answer (score 2):

The rlimit is placed on CPU time, not wall time. Depending on where your output is going, your program might be spending most of its time waiting on the output device. While it's doing that, it doesn't consume CPU time. So the program may run longer than 3 seconds, but if you check its CPU usage (`ps up $PID` and look under `TIME`) it will show less than 3 seconds used.