# rlimit_cpu not working on spawn call

Tags: ruby, linux-kernel, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a function that will execute a process and will kill it after 2 seconds:

```
def execute(command, input_file, output_file)
    pid =  Kernel.spawn(command,{
            STDIN => input_file,
            STDOUT => output_file,
            :rlimit_cpu => [2,2], #2 secs,
            :rlimit_nproc => 0,
            :rlimit_as => 16 * 1024 * 1024
            }
      );
    Process.wait(pid)
    puts "exit status = " + $?.exitstatus.to_s
    return File.read(output_file)
end
```

I tested this function with short-running processes and long-running processes (with a "sleep" call). The command always completes. I need that the spawn call kills the "command" after 2 seconds using rlimit_cpu. How I can do that?

EDIT: seems like rlimit_cpu does not works as I thought. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661020/setrlimit-isnt-reliable):

> The CPU limit is a limit on CPU seconds rather than elapsed time

Also:

> When you do the fib call, you hammer the CPU so that elapsed and CPU time are close (most of the process time is spent using the CPU). That's not the case when printing since most time there is spent in I/O.

I will use another approach, since I need to kill the process regardless if the process is CPU-bound or IO-bound

Answer (score 0):

To kill the process after two seconds, run a timer for two seconds, and then try to call `Process.kill` on the child.